# Différence entre « nom + de + article + nom » et « nom + de + nom » : quand mettre l'article ?

Tags: grammaire, articles

Je me demande quelle est la différence entre  *nom + de + article + nom* et  *nom + de + nom*.
Il me semble que si on emploie l'article, on exprime une possession. Alors que sans l'article, on parle de la manière ou de la qualité. Cependant, j'ai toujours une hésitation sur un emploi avec l'article ou sans l'article.

Par exemple, la différence entre *le sentiment de cœur* et *le sentiment du cœur* ? De la même façon : *la clé de porte* et *la clé de la porte* ?

C'est les deux expressions que j'ai en tête tout de suite, mais il y en a d'autres qui portent à confusion…

Et j'en profite pour demander : où peut-on trouver des références pour mieux comprendre la nuance entre ces deux expressions ?

Answer (score 17):

L'utilisation de l'article défini dans ce contexte est similaire à son utilisation classique : il indique que l'élément qu'il précède est un exemplaire précis, connu par le contexte.

Prenons comme exemple : « C'est une clé de la porte. » et « C'est une clé de porte. »

- Dans le premier cas, la clé ouvre une porte bien précise : celle dont on est en train de parler d'après le contexte.
- Dans le second cas, la clé ouvre une porte, mais il n'est pas précisé laquelle. L'accent est donc mis sur la nature de la clé : c'est une clé « de porte », par opposition à une clé « de cadenas » ou « de coffre ».

Comme autres exemples, on peut considérer :

- « un jouet de chat » (un jouet *pour les chats*) et « un jouet du chat » (un jouet *qui appartient au chat dont on est en train de parler*).
- « du lait de vache » et « du lait de la vache » : dans le second cas on parle d'*une vache en particulier* (celle du fermier voisin par exemple), alors que dans le premier cas, on dit que le lait a été fait par une vache, mais sans préciser ou savoir laquelle.

Comment: Merci pour votre explication, cela me donne une bonne piste.

Answer (score 6):

Lorsque la préposition *de* est suivie directement d'un nom sans article, il s'agit de l'[article partitif](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_partitif) (qui est d'habitude formé de *de* suivi de l'article défini, contractés au masculin singulier et au pluriel : l'article partitif est normalement *du*, *de la*, *de l'*, *des*). L'article partitif indique que l'on se réfère au concept de façon partielle.

Lorsque la préposition *de* est suivie de l'article défini (qui sont aussi contractés au masculin singulier et au pluriel), l'article défini a sa valeur habituelle : il s'agit soit d'un concept dans son ensemble, soit d'une référence à un objet déjà mentionné.

Dans « la clé de [la] porte », la distinction est claire. « La clé de la porte » est la clé qui ouvre la porte qui a été mentionnée auparavant dans la conversation, ou qui est évidente au vu de la conversation ; la clé n'a pas forcément déjà été mentionnée.

> As-tu pris le courrier ? — Non, je n'ai pas la clé de la boîte aux lettres.

« La clé de porte » désigne une clé qui ouvre une porte (et non, par exemple, un tiroir) ; l'article *la* devant *clé* implique que la clé a déjà été mentionnée, et le complément « de porte » donne une information sur la nature de cette clé.

> J'ai oublié ce qu'est cette clé sur mon trousseau. On dirait une clé de boîte aux lettres.

Avec des expressions comme « un sentiment de/du coeur », la nuance peut être plus vague. Aucune de ces expressions ne me paraît vraiment naturelle. On dit, par exemple, « une affaire de cœur » pour (en gros) une histoire d'amour ; le cœur est le siège métaphorique des sentiments, et une affaire de cœur affecte le cœur de la ou les personnes concernées. Par contre, on parle des « [Restos du cœur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restaurants_du_C%C5%93ur) » car le principe de ces restaurants (aider les personnes démunies) part du cœur (ici dans son rôle métaphorique d'origine de la charité) ; on peut dire de même (et c'est de là que vient le nom des Restos du cœur) que quelque chose « vient du cœur » pour signifier que c'est un exemple d'action charitable. On parle aussi de « chirurgie du cœur » ; ici il s'agit de l'organe en général.

Comment: Merci pour votre explication. La distinction entre l'article défini et l'article partitif m'est très utile.

Comment: Pour le sentiment de/du coeur, je voudrais dire que c'est le coeur qui sent qch, son role s'oppose donc à l'esprit.Peut etre on peut dire le sentiment de coeur (c'est le coeur qui sent, non l'esprit ou l'intelligence) ou le sentiment du coeur(un sentiment qui vient du coeur). Je suis toujours confus...