# Quand faut-il utiliser DE et quand faut-il utiliser DU ?

Tags: grammaire

J'ai lu un document et le sens de deux mots grammaticaux est confus dans mon esprit. J'ai vu les deux groupes nominaux suivants:

Affinage **du** carnet **de** produit

Feuille **de** route **du** produit

Je ne sais pas pourquoi on dit "carnet **de** produit" ni pourquoi on ne dirait pas "route **de** produit" ?

Comment: Aussi [Différence entre « nom + de + article + nom » et « nom + de + nom » : quand mettre l'article ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8153/diff%c3%a9rence-entre-nom-de-article-nom-et-nom-de-nom-quand-mett)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pour le même carnet vous pouvez utiliser soit "de" soit "du" dans certains cas, mais le point de vue diffère.  "Carnet **de** produit" signifie que le carnet est un carnet spécial conçu pour un produit ou plusieurs produits; c'est une locution qui décrit une *sorte* de carnet; il n'y a pas d'article devant le mot "carnet".
En disant "carnet **du** produit" on dit en fait "*carnet **de le** produit*" mais cette forme n'est jamais utilisée, ce qui la rend incorrecte; à sa place on dit "du"; en d'autres mots "du" a le sens de  "de le", où "de" est une préposition et "le" l'article défini masculin. En conséquence, le mot "produit" ne désigne plus n'importe quel produit mais un produit particulier que le contexte doit rendre explicite; on dit que "produit" est déterminé par "l'article "le". De plus "carnet du produit" ne désigne plus seulement une sorte de carnet mais d'abord, pour le sens de la phrase, un carnet (sous-entendu, d'une sorte donnée) en tant qu'*associé* à un produit.

*Exemples*

- Pour le produit X il faut un carnet **de** produit mais pour le produit Y il n'en faut pas. (*On utilise seulement "de" dans le présent cas parce qu'on parle de la sorte de carnet et d'aucun carnet en tant qu'assigné à un produit donné.*)
- — Il a plusieurs produits; le produit Y parmi ceux-ci est défectueux.
  — Faites moi voir le carnet **du/de** produit, je dois vérifier quelque chose. (*Vous pouvez choisir.*)
  *alternative*
  — Faites moi voir le carnet **du** produit Y, je dois vérifier quelque chose. (*Dans ce cas vous ne pouvez pas choisir parce que "produit" est déterminé par "Y" et donc l'article "le" doit figurer dans la syntaxe.*)
- Lorsque vous avez des réclamations vous devez nous envoyer le carnet **du/de** produit, sinon nous ne pouvons pas donner suite à votre demande. (*Le choix de l'un ou de l'autre est possible parce que les produits en question ont tous un carnet et donc on peut référer  à un carnet en tant que sorte ou bien en tant que carnet attribué à un produit donné. Lorsque "de" est utilisé il est sous-entendu que la carte de produit est celle qui concerne le produit sujet à une réclamation.*)

*carnet **de** produit*: définition — carnet conçu pour décrire un produit

*carnet **du** produit*: définition — carnet de produit associé à un produit donné

Answer (score 4):

In these examples, the *de* links two parts of a general term, while the *du* links such a term to a specific instance of something.

Your general terms here are *carnet de produit* and *feuille de route*.

*Affinage du carnet de produit* is therefore the *affinage* of THE — *du* — particular *carnet de produit* that you have before you.

*Feuille de route du produit* is the *feuille de route* of THE — *du* — particular *produit* you have.