# De or de le (de la)?

Tags: grammaire

Why is it: la pomme ***de*** terre (***NOT*** la pomme ***de la*** terre), and why is it: la grammaire ***du*** français (la grammaire ***de le*** français)?
In other words, why do I need to say de le in the second phrase and there is no definite article in the first one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Différence entre « nom + de + article + nom » et « nom + de + nom » : quand mettre l'article ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8153/diff%c3%a9rence-entre-nom-de-article-nom-et-nom-de-nom-quand-mett)

Answer (score 2):

Dans une construction nom + préposition + nom, sans déterminant devant le deuxième nom, le deuxième nom est utilisé comme le sont certains adjectifs postposés (canard sauvage) avec valeur distinctive. Cela permet d’établir une sous-classe.

Exemple : le chien de berger, le bateau à voile.

S’il on met un déterminant devant le deuxième nom, alors on ne désigne plus la classe mais un objet ou un individu particulier.

Exemple : le chien du berger, le bateau à la voile blanche

D’autre part, de + le se contracte toujours en du.