# Une crise « de » ou « de le/la » ?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, expressions-idiomatiques, articles, formulation-idiomatique

Une crise **de** panique, une crise **de la** dette, la crise **de** 2007, la crise **de l**'emploi.

Selon les règles que je peux trouver, par exemple:

> DE + nom avec article : valeur particulière, concrète
>
> DE + nom sans article : valeur générale, abstraite

je serais enclin à omettre l'article defini dans tous les exemples ci-dessus. Concrètement, je dirais

> la crise d'emploi

au lieu de

> la crise de l'emploi

parce que pour moi, le mot « emploi » est quelque chose de général, et qui qualifie le mot « crise ». On peut prendre un exemple plus facile pour illustrer ce point, que j'estime être similaire : un directeur de banque et le directeur de la banque.

**Pour résumer** : quelle règle s'applique dans les exemples ci-dessus, et comment explique-t-on les differences apparentes ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Différence entre « nom + de + article + nom » et « nom + de + nom » : quand mettre l'article ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8153/diff%c3%a9rence-entre-nom-de-article-nom-et-nom-de-nom-quand-mett)

Answer (score 3):

**Une crise de panique**           Il ne faut jamais d'article parce que « de » introduit un phénomène qui se manifeste par crises. ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de) : b) Subst. + de. *De* a une valeur partitive, **proche** de celle de l'article partitif.)

- crise d'épilepsie, crise de colère, crise d'anxiété, crise de délire,

**Une crise de la dette**           Les dettes ne sont pas de la nature des choses qui se manifestent par crises, donc on ne peut jamais trouver « crise de dette » ; si on trouve « crise de la dette », alors « de » n'a plus la même fonction (proche du partitif), mais il a la fonction déterminative de préciser une référence essentielle, et il s'agit alors d'une dette particulière. Par exemple, dans le cas d'une dette nationale qui aura causé une crise particulière, on peut parler de « La crise de la dette nationale » ou de façon plus courte, de « la crise de la dette ».

- La crise de la dette a porté le coup de grâce à ce parti politique. (*référence à la cause de la crise*)
- La crise de l'année 1962 a mis le feu aux poudres. (*référence au point dans le temps où la crise se manifeste*)

**la crise de 2007**           traité ci-dessus en cela que « crise de 2007 » n'est qu'une abréviation pour « crise de l'année 2007 ».

**la crise de l'emploi**           Même chose que pour « crise de la dette » ; une référence est faite à ce qui est la cause de la crise.

Il faut remarquer que dans « crise de panique » on fait bien référence à ce qui est la cause de la crise implicitement, mais ce n'est pas la fonction que l'on reconnait à « de » dans ce cas ; il n'y a donc pas de contradiction. Disons que dans ces cas ou une fonction proche de celle du partitif est reconnue, c'est celle-là qui prime.

L'exemple « [directeur de banque] (caractérisation)/[directeur de la banque] (qualité) » n'est pas pertinent dans cette question ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de) 3. La modalité est une destination habituelle ou occasionnelle d'une pers., d'un animal ou d'une chose (but, fin, usage); *de* signifie *pour* et introduit un compl. déterminatif (cf. aussi caractérisation, genre, espèce, qualité, etc.). β) Destination professionnelle. Les deux employés de bureau qui ont trop « pensé » à mille théories).