# Est ce que l'utilisation de la préposition "de" à la place de "de la" peut changer carrément le sens de la phrase ?

Tags: sens, prépositions, de

Voilà deux exemples.

> les conditions d'emploi des travailleurs.

> les conditions de l'emploi des travailleurs.

J'ai l'impression que le sens  diffère carrément entre les deux phrases ( j'ai peut-être tort ! ).

Pour moi, dans la première phrase, on parle des prérequis que les travailleurs doivent avoir. Tandis que dans la deuxième phrase, le terme "**conditions**" fait référence au statut ou bien à l'état du processus de recrutement. (Comme dans la phrase : les conditions de la femme).

Est-ce que ce que j'ai compris des deux phrases est correct ?

Sinon, quelle est la différence entre les deux ?

Comment: Relié : https://french.stackexchange.com/q/8153/1893

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Réponse dans le cas des deux exemples* (généralisation incertaine)

Il n'y a pas de différence entre les deux. Lorsque « emploi » est complémenté par « des travailleurs », l'expression n'est pas utilisée, mais pourrait l'être, parce que correcte.

([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Pour_sortir_les_allumetti%C3%A8res_de_l_ombr/PMduEAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22les+conditions+de+l%27+emploi%22&pg=PT109&printsec=frontcover))  Tout débute lorsque la compagnie prend certaines décisions qui dégradent les conditions de l'emploi des allumettières, les obligeant à se conformer à un système de doubles équipes,

[image]

https://www.google.com/search?q=%22les%20conditions%20d%27emploi%20des%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr

https://www.google.com/search?q=%22les%20conditions%20de%20l%27%20emploi%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr

Lorsque « emploi » n'est pas complémenté par « des travailleurs » l'expression est peu utilisée.

[image]

https://www.google.com/search?q=%22les%20conditions%20d%27emploi%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr

Les deux réfèrent aux conditions que l'employeur doit respecter et aux conditions que l'employé doit remplir.

Dans le texte du PO la phrase suivante a été laissée inchangée pour ne pas déformer l'idée originelle ; cependant elle est incorrecte.

> Pour moi, dans la première phrase, on parle des prérequis que les travailleurs doivent en avoir.

« doivent en avoir » n'est pas grammatical à cet endroit. De plus, ce que l'on semble avoir eu l'intention d'exprimer en écrivant cette phrase serait ce que le contenu de la phrase suivante exprime.

> Pour moi, dans la première phrase, on parle des prérequis que les travailleurs doivent remplir.

Il peut  y avoir une différence par exemple entre « les méthodes de recherche » et « les méthodes de la recherche », mais  on doit donner à « recherche » un sens proche de « recherche scientifique » (synonyme de « recherche » 2) , c'est à dire le sens de « recherche particulière dans une discipline  scientifique ». Les méthodes de recherche sont les méthodes utilisées dans une certaine recherche, alors que les méthodes de *la* recherche sont celles utilisées en général en science.

[image]

https://www.google.com/search?q=%22m%C3%A9thodes%20de%20recherche%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr

https://www.google.com/search?q=%22m%C3%A9thodes%20de%20recherche%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse. Ça m'a trop aidé.